# select all from table using date with time

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can I get the last recorded data of the time 23:59 from yesterday and the day before?

my code doesn't have a filter of the time yet so it only shows all the data from yesterday and the day before.

```
select *
from tbl_Total
where date between  DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please add some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return yestarday date with time 23:59:59.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE) as varchar(12)) +' 23:59:59' as datetime2)
```

So you can use it in your query:

```
select *
from tbl_Total
where date between  DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) AND CAST(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as DATE) as varchar(12)) +' 23:59:59' as datetime2)
```

**EDIT:** More elegant way:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

This query returns yesterday date with time 23:59:59.

**EDIT2:** If you want to return the day before with time 23:59:59 you need to use this query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0))
```

If you want to obtain any other day you can change number `2` and test it.

Comment: I also need to return the day before yesterday at the same time @Rokuto

Comment: @hikarisakunami With hour 00:00:00 or 23:59:59?

Comment: with the hour 23:59. can I get the last recorded data of the time 23:59?

Comment: @hikarisakunami I've updated answer. Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your case,

```
select * from tbl_Total as of timestamp timestamp '2017-07-19 23:59:59'
```

and

```
select * from tbl_Total as of timestamp timestamp '2017-07-18 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from tbl_Total
where date between  dateadd(day,-3,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),112)) AND dateadd(day,-3,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),112)+ ' 23:59:59:997' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know the exact time you can get the latest rows using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
with cte as
 ( select *,
      row_number() -- for each day sorted descending
      over (partition by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0)
      order by date desc) as rn
   from tbl_Total
   where -- yesterday between 23:59 and 23:59:99.999
    (     date >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0) - (1.0/1440)
      and date <  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0)
    )
   or    -- day before yesterday between 23:59 and 23:59:99.999
    (     date >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0) - (1.0/1440)
      and date <  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0)
    )
 )
select * from cte
where rn = 1 --latest row only
```